# Changing EXIF Data Of Image File Using PHP

Tags: php

I've successfully changed the IPTC tags using the following code. But not able to modify the EXIF meta such as Author, Description etc. Here's the code I've used for IPTC:

```
<?php

function iptc_make_tag($rec, $data, $value)
{
    $length = strlen($value);
    $retval = chr(0x1C) . chr($rec) . chr($data);

    if($length < 0x8000)
    {
        $retval .= chr($length >> 8) .  chr($length & 0xFF);
    }
    else
    {
        $retval .= chr(0x80) . 
                   chr(0x04) . 
                   chr(($length >> 24) & 0xFF) . 
                   chr(($length >> 16) & 0xFF) . 
                   chr(($length >> 8) & 0xFF) . 
                   chr($length & 0xFF);
    }

    return $retval . $value;
}

// Path to jpeg file
$path = 'test.jpg';

// Set the IPTC tags
$iptc = array(
    '2#105' => 'Headline Here',
    '2#005' => 'Title Here',
    '2#120' => 'Caption Here',
    '2#116' => 'Copyright Here',
    '2#025' => 'KW Here',
    '2#110' => 'Credit Here',
    '2#080' => 'Creator here',



);

// Convert the IPTC tags into binary code
$data = '';

foreach($iptc as $tag => $string)
{
    $tag = substr($tag, 2);
    $data .= iptc_make_tag(2, $tag, $string);
}

// Embed the IPTC data
$content = iptcembed($data, $path);

// Write the new image data out to the file.
$fp = fopen($path, "wb");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

When I check the Image Meta using https://www.thexifer.net/ website, it shows the IPTC tags but EXIF general fields are empty.

Answer (score -1):

The code works, I tested on my server.
The file or the folder has to have writing rights for that to work on PHP 7.2.

Comment: It good that it works on your server, but it would be more helpful to know what PHP version do you use, what extensions are installed there and other helpful information to reproduce it